# C++ xml parser with unicode support & without COM registration

Tags: c++, c, xml, xml-parsing

I need to use a C++ XML parser/writer for implementing virtual registry on the basis of the following 2 conditions.

1. It should not write entries in registry
2. It should support unicode characters.

I have tried the following parsers but none have solved the 2 conditions:

- Msxml (writes in to registry for COM creation)
- Xerces (registers COM)
- Tiny Xml (no entries in reg, but does not support unicode characters)
- Rapid Xml (no unicode uspport)

So please if you could know any which solves my 2 condition, please let me know

Comment: Xerces registers COM? You've probably used someone's COM wrapper on top of Xerces' native API. http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinyxml is enought. So you can conversion your unicode characters to utf8 first.

Comment: Is it possible to convert unicode in Utf-8. Can you please explain it.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode in 8-bit bytes. All 7-bit ASCII characters encode to single bytes as themselves. All other unicode code points encode to sequences of two or more bytes all of which have their high bit set and none of which can be 0. That makes is easy to use as if it were a normal stream of bytes.

Comment: Hi Wells, It works mate. I use CW2A and CA2W function to achieve the UTF8 conversion.  Hi, RBerteig  - Thanks for your nice explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Congratulate!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/).